# jQuery on scroll z-index issue with position:fixed

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm working on layout where parent div has 100% width & height of window size.

It's child div has fixed dimension say : 400px with overflow : auto as I want to show scrollbar.

This child div has one element to which I want add position : fixed on scroll event.

My problem is whenever I add position : fixed to one of the element inside child div using jQuery

scroll event, It pops-out of child div even being child div has higher z-index & overflow : auto

Here is working [Code & Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWH3S/1/)

What is the issue here ? What needs to be fixed ??

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <p id="head">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #bbb;
    z-index: 999
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 99
}
p {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px;
}
#head {
    background: green
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

JS

```
$("#content").scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#head').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#head').removeClass('fixed');
    }         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position fixed is always relative to the viewport so the width of 100% that you have applied to it will always do that.

you can apply width inherit to fixed elements and that does the trick in some browsers but since you also have padding on the element the parent width wont do the trick either

you will have to hard code a width of 320px to the p elements in this case or a javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Please set 

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this if helps: http://jsfiddle.net/nWH3S/3/

```
$("#content").scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {

    $('#head').addClass('fixed').css({
        width: $("#content").innerWidth()-20+"px"
    });
  } else {
    $('#head').removeClass('fixed').css({
        width: $(this).width()
    });
  }
});
```

and chekout the fiddle.

and this one needs to be fixed like this:

```
p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;// just made the padding for top bottom.
  margin:0;
}
```